Embedding plotly interactive figures in a confluence page
Is there a way to embed my plotly figures in a confluence page? Here's what I've tried:
import plotly.express as px
x = [1,1,2,3,3,3,4,5]
fig = px.histogram(x=x)
fig.write_html('my.html')

Then I tried copy-pasting the HTML from my.html into a HTML macro in a Confluence page (using this app), but it doesn't display.
Any idea how this should be done?

You just need the graph div in the output (not a complete HTML document), also you can use plotlyjs CDN to save 3MB : fig.write_html('my.html', include_plotlyjs='cdn', full_html=False). Regarding the HTML macro, I would try (I didn't) HTML for Confluence or HTML Macro for Confluence Cloud.
